# Calculating polygon area in R using sf - inconsistency with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: r, arcgis-pro, sf

I am working with a few shapefiles in R and trying to calculate area of the individual polygons within each shapefile. One of them seems to be working appropriately - when I calculate area using "st_area", the result is almost the same as the provided shape_area (it is a state/gov't file which includes that field). The data can be found here under land ownership: https://www.fire.ca.gov/what-we-do/fire-resource-assessment-program/gis-mapping-and-data-analytics

The other file has some multipolygon geometry (information about the dataset found here https://www.fs.usda.gov/rds/archive/products/RDS-2015-0012-4/_metadata_RDS-2015-0012-4.html#Identification_Information) and the results when I use st_area are quite a bit larger than the given shape_area (e.g., 50,000 m2 for shape_area, and 80,000 m2 using st_area). When I use "calculate geometry" in arcgis pro, the results match shape_area, but not the st_area.

A bit confusing, since it works fine for the first file. I am assuming it has to do with the multipolygon characteristics, but I am not sure. Any ideas on how I can accurately calculate area for this shapefile using R? I need to process it and so the file will change down the line, so the given shape_area is not sufficient.

Update: I have figured out the reason is that the shapefile was reprojected from CA - albers to WGS84. When I use the original albers file, the estimates are the same. However, the differences still seem very extreme. Is this to be expected?

Comment: You could explode the geometry using `sf::st_cast(x, "POLYGON")` to see how close it is to the area as multipart geometry.

Comment: I tried this and it did split some of the geometries, but the inconsistency in the area calculations still persists. Any thoughts on what could be impacting the area calculation within R, but not within ArcGIS pro?

Comment: Is one or other of the systems using spherical geometry rather than planar geometry to compute the area? See `?sf_use_s2`